# C# Temperature Converter showing incorrect results for Celsius

Tags: c#

I'm a C# beginner, and was practicing on a temp converter in console app, when I do F to C it works just fine, but when I do C to F it just shows crazy numbers... for 100 C it shows = 16000+ F, 30 C = 5000+ F, etc. The problem may be obvious but I really can't see what's wrong :/

```
static void Celsius() // CELSIUS //
        {
            double celsiusInput;
            string restart = "";
            Console.Write("You chose Celsius! Please, insert an number in C to convert it to F: ");
            celsiusInput = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + (celsiusInput * 1.8) + 32);
            Console.Write("Type 'yes' to restart, or type 'no' to close: ");
            restart = Console.ReadLine();
            if (restart == "yes" || restart == "Yes" || restart == "YES")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Main();
            }
            else if (restart == "no" || restart == "No" || restart == "NO")
            {
                ExitApp();
            }

        }
        static void Fahrenheit() // FAHRENHEIT // 
        {
            double fInput;
            string restart = "";
            Console.Write("You chose Fahrenheit! Please, insert an number in F to convert it to C: ");
            fInput = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + (fInput - 32) / 1.8);
            Console.Write("Type 'yes' to restart, or type 'no' to close: ");
            restart = Console.ReadLine();
            if (restart == "yes")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Main();
            }
            else if (restart == "no")
            {
                ExitApp();
            }
```

Comment: @Andy so I was using the same one for both, but when I was trying to fix the issue with Cels i made a little mistake, however it makes no difference

Comment: To avoid these types of mistakes, it's often better to set the result of a mathematic operation to a variable and then output the string representation of that variable.

Comment: You see that others have already answered your question but let me also provide you with a great tip for checking valid user input:
You don't need to check for every possible combination of caps in a word, simply use the string ToLower() or ToUpper() method and then do the comparison like  that.

So instead of checking for 3 conditions, you just use `if( restart.ToUpper().equals("YES")) { //do thing }`

Comment: @TheRedMetalRooster I was also wondering is these such a thing, I will consider using .ToUpper next time definitely :), thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + (celsiusInput * 1.8) + 32);
```

It concatenates the following `strings` (I used 100 as input):

- `"The answer is: "`
- `"180"`
- `"32"`

resulting in the string `"The answer is: 18030"`.

You probably want to adjust your parentheses like this so that the second `+` is the arithmetic operator and not the string concatenation operator:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + (celsiusInput * 1.8 + 32));
```

That way you do all of your arithmetic operations first, then concatenate the strings.

Comment: Alternatively, make setting the result and outputting it two different operations (i.e. have an explicit result variable).

Comment: Just to add to what @mjwills has said... By putting the result of the calculation in an explicit variable, you can better debug your program.  As you step through, you could see the value of that calculation.  It also segregates the operations nicely: first you do the calculation, then you worry about the user interface.  Don't worry that it will make your program bigger or slower; the compiler and/or *JITter* will fold the two operations into one when you create a *Release* build.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the operations priority as you can see you are calculating in the `Console.WriteLine` call appending the answer to `string`.
So the first thing it do it calculates `(celsiusInput * 1.8)` then appends the result to `"The answer is: "` then appends `32` to the previous result but the previous expression is a string so it appends `32` as `string` and `+` here is concatenating operator not Summing because the left side is string.
You can add braces to prioritize the calculations.

this is not a part of your question but still 
Another thing you could do is using `.ToUpper()` which convert the string to Upper case and this will cut your conditions to one.

```
        static void Celsius() // CELSIUS //
        {
            double celsiusInput;
            string restart = "";
            Console.Write("You chose Celsius! Please, insert an number in C to convert it to F: ");
            celsiusInput = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + ( (celsiusInput * 1.8) + 32));
            Console.Write("Type 'yes' to restart, or type 'no' to close: ");
            restart = Console.ReadLine();
            if (restart.ToUpper() ==  "YES")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Main();
            }
            else if (restart.ToUpper() == "NO")
            {
                ExitApp();
            }

        }
```